# Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't support management (getQueueNames)

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am running an embedded Artemis (`EmbeddedJMSResource`) and everything works well except when I want to use the management to get a list of queue names.

I can see in the code (`ClientRequestor`) that a request is made using requestProducer and that replyConsumer then waits for a response. However the consumer doesn;t pick up any answer. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Also, please provide the code where you're doing the actual management operation.